# Unable to connect to Azure Keyvault when I deploy ASP.NET Core 6 Web API (C#) , the docker image to docker desktop app

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault, docker-desktop, azure-identity

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in C# with Docker support and it worked perfectly when I try to run from Visual Studio. When I deploy the docker build image to docker desktop app, I get an error:

> <sup>2024-03-29 17:50:53 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53       Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53       Hosting environment: Development
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:53       Content root path: /app/
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 info: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Getting token Async
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 info: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Use Key Vault True
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 info: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Keyvault : : XXXXX
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 info: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Keyvault URL : : https://XXXXX.vault.azure.net
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 info: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Creating Secret client
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59 info: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:50:59       Getting Secret
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02 fail: WebApplication Controllers.HealthController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02       Health Controller : InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: Persistence check failed. Inspect inner exception for details
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02       Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: Persistence check failed. Inspect inner exception for details
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02        ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.MsalCachePersistenceException: Persistence check failed. Inspect inner exception for details
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02        ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libsecret-1.so.0' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibsecret-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.Libsecret.secret_schema_new(String name, Int32 flags, String attribute1, Int32 attribute1Type, String attribute2, Int32 attribute2Type, IntPtr end)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.LinuxKeyringAccessor.GetLibsecretSchema()
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.LinuxKeyringAccessor.Write(Byte[] data)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.Storage.VerifyPersistence()
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.Storage.VerifyPersistence()
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.MsalCacheHelper.VerifyPersistence()
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.MsalCacheHelperWrapper.VerifyPersistence()
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.TokenCache.GetCacheHelperAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.TokenCache.GetCacheHelperAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.TokenCache.RegisterCache(Boolean async, ITokenCache tokenCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.MsalClientBase GetClientAsync(Boolean enableCae, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.MsalPublicClient.AcquireTokenInteractiveCoreAsync(String[] scopes, String claims, Prompt prompt, String loginHint, String tenantId, Boolean enableCae, BrowserCustomizationOptions browserOptions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.MsalPublicClient.AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync(String[] scopes, String claims, Prompt prompt, String loginHint, String tenantId, Boolean enableCae, BrowserCustomizationOptions browserOptions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential.GetTokenViaBrowserLoginAsync(TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage, Boolean isCredentialUnavailable)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage, Boolean isCredentialUnavailable)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueFromCredentialAsync(TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AuthenticateAndAuthorizeRequestAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.AuthorizeRequestOnChallengeAsyncInternal(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory 1 pipeline, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory 1 pipeline, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory 1 pipeline, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory 1 pipeline, Boolean async)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequestAsync[TResult](RequestMethod method, Func 1 resultFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String[] path)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient.GetSecretAsync(String name, String version, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at WebApplication Controllers.AdministratorControllerBase.GetSpnSecretAsync(String secretKey) in /src/WebApplication1/Controllers/AdministratorControllerBase.cs:line 43
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at WebApplication Controllers.AdministratorControllerBase.GetTokenAsync() in /src/WebApplication1/Controllers/AdministratorControllerBase.cs:line 59
> 2024-03-29 17:51:02          at WebApplication Controllers.HealthController.Get() in /src/WebApplication1/Controllers/HealthController.cs:line 30
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10 info: WebApplication1 Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10       Use Key Vault True
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10 info: WebApplication Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10       Keyvault : : XXXXX
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10 info: WebApplication Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10       Keyvault URL : : https://XXXX.vault.azure.net
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10 info: WebApplication Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10       Creating Secret client
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10 info: WebApplication Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
> 2024-03-29 17:51:10       Getting Secret
> 2024-03-29 19:13:04 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> 2024-03-29 19:13:04       Application is shutting down...</sup>

I also tried to run the project with .NET 7 and used the latest packages and followed the checked on the
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28120

This is my code:

```
protected static async Task<string> GetSpnSecretAsync(string secretKey)
{
    var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT");

    var keyVaultUrl = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(includeInteractiveCredentials: true);
    var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential: credential);

    var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretKey);

    var secretValue = secret.Value.Value;

    return secretValue;
}
```